# How to use PS3 controller via Bluetooth?

Tags: ps3, controllers

I'm using Windows 10. I've two USB Bluetooth adapter. One of them used to connect my magic keyboard and magic mouse. The other one to connect my PS3 Controller to my PC. I use SCPToolkit but when I check the dongle #2 to overwrite drivers my input devices doesn't work.

How can I connect via bluetooth my PS3 Controller to the second dongle without overwrite drivers of my first BT adapter?

Comment: Solved by deleting old drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Uninstall previous drivers

- Start Menu > Search > Type: **cmd** > Type: *net stop "SCP DS3 Service"*
- Control Panel > **Uninstall a program** > *SCPtool kit*
- **Delete** *C:/Program Files/Scarlet.Crush Productions* folder
- **Delete** *HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Scarlet.Crush Productions* folder from **regedit**

## Install PS3 controller via Bluetooth

- Install [**ScpToolkit**](https://github.com/nefarius/ScpToolkit/releases) with high privileges
- Plug in the PS3 controller
- Follow steps and select the PS3 dualshock controller and the right USB dongle for the bluetooth.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can connect your ps3 controller viz blutooth to your computer I kno with the ps4 controller I have to connect it by my usb cord/charger cord and it works that way have you tried connecting your ps3 controller by the charging cord?

Comment: You *can* use Bluetooth, both cable and bluetooth work well, you just need different drivers